# eclipse doesn't see basic libraries

Tags: eclipse

I try to use eclipse 3.7.2 with ubuntu 12.10.

When I use command line it's ok (all necessary jdk and jre libraries are installed). But if I try to write just a simple "Hello World" with eclipse I see that it doesn't know anything about Object class, String class, e.t.c.

I've tried to show eclipse where basic .jar files are but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, right click on your project go to "Properties -> Java BuildPath -> Libraries"
Click "Add Libraries" -> "Select JRE System Library" -> "Select your JRE" -> "Finish" -> "OK"

Now you project is configured to use the selected version of your JRE.

[image]
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks you! Now eclipse doesn't underline many previous mistakes but still gives me the following mistake: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main

Comment: It means that your jvm cannot find the class called "Main"

Comment: Try putting it in, and declaring it to be in, a Package.